# C# Chart alignment axis label

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have some custom labels in column chart (a bit of my code):

```
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 0;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 10);
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.LightGray;

        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = false;


        DateTime minDate = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString());
        DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Date"].ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(minDate.ToOADate(),
                                                                       minDate.AddDays(6).ToOADate(),
                                                                       minDate.ToShortDateString() + "-" + minDate.AddDays(6).ToShortDateString(),
                                                                       0,
                                                                       LabelMarkStyle.None));
            minDate = minDate.AddDays(7);
        }
```

So since my custom lable text is so long `minDate.ToShortDateString() + "-" + minDate.AddDays(6).ToShortDateString()` it looks like

[image]

How can i moved to the left axis lables if i can?

Comment: My suggestion would be to shorten the labels. From a usability perspective, they are difficult to read, and the information gets lost. Just use e.g. 30/3 - 5/4, or even, since these seem to be weeks, just the start date, e.g. 30/3, 6/4, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides shortening the content to avoid any redundancy you could try to trick the label formatter by adding a few blanks to the right, then a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) and then a \n.

Here is the result before and after:

[image][image]

I have used this code:

```
  A.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM.dd.yy";
  A.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM.dd.yy        " + ((char)160) + "\n";
```

Comment: `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy           " + ((char)160) + "\n";` - nothing has changed

Comment: But for AxisY it works `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "##                  " + ((char)160) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n";`

Comment: Note the blanks that force the label to shift!

Comment: OK - but it does not work may be for DateTime format?

Comment: OK - I am very sorry, but format i am using is `minDate.ToShortDateString() + "-" + minDate.AddDays(6).ToShortDateString()`

Comment: Am i right accordingly your example: `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy-dd.MM.yyyy                          " + ((char)160) + "\n"`

Comment: Well, the added blanks (which you don't have) will move the label to the left. But this will only work if there is enough room. You may have to enlarge the AxisX.Interval