# How to make sure endlabels are always visible on c# chart x axis

Tags: c#, charts

I have created a chart in the image below and I need to insert in addition to the existing labels, the end labels on the extreme left and right of the x-axis. There are numerous datapoints and therefore I cannot set the interval to 1 for the labels as they'll clutter the axis. I have already tried setting the property

```
 chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
```

but it doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
```

Or probably you will have to add the labels yourself,
you can either use [DataPoint.AxisLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx):

```
chartHistory.Series[0].Points[0].AxisLabel = "5/4/2010";
```

or more flexibly:

```
chartHistory.Series[0].Points[0].AxisLabel = 
System.DateTime.FromOADate(chartHistory.Series[0].Points[0].XValue).ToShortDateString();
```

(and the same for the last point in series)

or you can [add a custom label to the AxisX control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.customlabels%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0, 20, "5/4/2010");
```

[See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692353/2224701) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30474393/2224701).

Comment: Thanks, I had to use the DataPoint.Axislabel Property.