# How can i make the label to be left aligned in MS Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I am using MS Chart control. I have label on X axis. How can I make the label to be left aligned. Currently by default it is aligned in center. For eg in below chart, I want the label like Jun, Jul to start from left.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Test Title";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
```

If your layout is from left to right, StringAlignment.Near will align it left, otherwise it will align it to the right.

Comment: That's a lot more tricky.  Looks like someone may have done what you are asking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474393/c-sharp-chart-alignment-axis-label